# Lots of empty lines in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I read `.html()` at the end of this snippet, I get this result :

```
"



<div style="left: 0px;" class="text">Test1</div><div style="left: 1px;" class="text">Test2</div><div style="left: 2px;" class="text">Test3</div>"
```

**Why all these empty lines?**

*Note: in the JS part, I detach all the `.text` elements, apply some modifications on them, and reappend them to the DOM. I need to do that in my real code, for some reasons that would be out of topic here.*

---

```js
$("#blah").append($(".text").detach().each(function(i) {
   this.style.left = Math.random() * 10 + 'px'; this.style.top = i*10 + 'px'; 
}));
console.log($("#blah").html());
```

```css
.text {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
<div id="blah">
  <div class="text" >Test1</div>
  <div class="text" >Test2</div>
  <div class="text" >Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Been playing with your rather cool demo website and am quite impressed, except for performance. You need to, at least, fade out really large elements "behind the camera" and possibly remove them. Rendering massive scaled-up fonts causes browsers to grind to a halt. Also replacing really small groups of items with a single element (e.g. faint grey rectangles or something nicer?) will help navigate as it is very easy to lose small content in the big picture. Well done though :)

Comment: Thanks for these nice comments @TrueBlueAussie. I will post the project soon open-source on GitHub... Will you help me ? :)
Sidenote: which browser do you use? Chrome? It seems that the project is really slow on Chrome when we zoom a lot...  It's strange becuse it's fast on Firefox or IE if we zoom a lot!

Comment: Yes, this is one of the first open-source projects I would consider working on :) I *was* using Chrome. My early background was writing video games, so those type of culling techniques will help performance.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie : here it is https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/ ! Let's meet there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to the detach and append the elements to change their style. You are basically accumulating all the whitespace *between elements* at the top and moving all the elements below the whitespace.

If your HTML looked like this the problem would not have been visible:

```
<div id="blah"><div class="text" >Test1</div><div class="text" >Test2</div> <div class="text" >Test3</div></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/not1yerc/

Basically do not detach and append. The changes occur on the same JS browser cycle so will not glitch:

```
$(".text").each(function(i) {
   this.style.left = Math.random() * 10 + 'px'; this.style.top = i*10 + 'px'; 
});
console.log($("#blah").html());
```

**The real problem:**

As the real problem is using detach and append to avoid `transition-delay` styling from firing, the real solution is to remove a specific transition class from the elements, change them, then add that class back.

e.g. have a new `transitions` class with the transitioning styles:

```
.transitions{
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

make sure all your `text` elements have that class as required. Then your code becomes:

```
$(".text").each(function(i) {
   // Remove the transitions styling class
   $(this).removeClass('transitions');

   // Change the layout without transitions
   this.style.left = Math.random() * 10 + 'px'; this.style.top = i*10 + 'px'; 

   // Restore the transitions styling class
   $(this).addClass('transitions');
});
```

This is much faster than detach and appending DOM elements and will not move the whitespace.

Comment: FacePalm :/  During all of this just didn't think of the real problem of why Op wants to do all this! I shouldn't stay back late at office :) +1 indeed.

Answer (score 2):

> Why all these empty lines?

Because they were in your initial DOM before you moved around nodes. If you have a look at the html source of `#blah`, you'll find four linebreaks - which are represented in the DOM as whitespace text nodes. Since you didn't remove them, they still reside in the DOM - only with no more `<div>`s in between them, making the lines *empty*.

Comment: Okay! How to make that the final DOM (after re-append them) has the breaklines at the good places, so that I will look clean (and not single-line-without-linebreak HTML code) ?

Comment: The DOM doesn't need to "look" clean. Whitespace nodes don't have any significance for rendering in block elements.

Comment: I want the DOM to look clean, because my code sometimes serializes or exports as HTML

Comment: In that case, remove empty text nodes by something like `$("#blah").contents().filter(function(el) { return el.nodeType == 3 && /^\s*$/.test(el.value); }).remove()`

Answer (score 0):

You have empty lines because of the whitespace in your markup. Also, as mentioned by others in comments, you don't need to `detach`. If you don't want to change your markup, then do a `.trim()`.

***Sample Snippet:***

```js
$("#blah").find(".text").each(function(i) {
   this.style.left = Math.random() * 10 + 'px'; this.style.top = i*10 + 'px'; 
   $(this).appendTo($("#blah"));
});
console.log($("#blah").html().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blah">
  <div class="text" >Test1</div>
  <div class="text" >Test2</div>
  <div class="text" >Test3</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, just remove the whitepsace from your markup in this case. As @trueblueassie mentioned, `.trim()` could be slow for large chunk of HTML string. And, then you don't even need to `.append()` to move things around.

```
<div id="blah"><div class="text" >Test1</div><div class="text" >Test2</div><div class="text" >Test3</div></div>
```

Comment: That trim is a relative slow solution *if it were applied to the content to remove the leading whitespace*. It has to reparse the HTML (which is apparently very large).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes. Agreed.

Comment: the HTML string *will be* very large (see my project with potentially thousands of text elements)

Comment: As I see it, in fact you don't need to `append` even. In place changes will work. And, if your HTML string is huge, then you need to change the markup to remove whitespaces.

Comment: In place changes is not possible, there is `transition-delay`... To avoid this, I detach, modify, reappend